# Как добавить новый тег после другого тега внутри тега?

Tags: javascript

Надо  внутри тега `article` добавить новый тег `hr` после каждого `p`( c помощью js). Попробовал такой способ:

```
var artic = document.getElementsByTagName('article')
var ptag = artic.getElementByTagName('p');

var newhr = document.createElement('hr');

artic.insertBefore(newhr, ptag);
```

Но это не помогло.
Как добавить новый тег `hr` после другого тега `p` внутри тега `article`?  Надо сделать без использовании `Class` and `Id`(У меня там есть несколько `p` и у каждого есть свой `Id` и `Class`)

Comment: Почему просто не использовать какой-нибудь :after и стилизовать его ?

Comment: Мне надо сделать с помощью js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [`.insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

```js
var ptag = document.getElementById('idName');

var newhr = document.createElement('hr');
ptag.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newhr);
```

```html
<article>
  <p id="idName">Paragraph</p>
</article>
```

Так же можно воспользоваться тем же [`.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), передавая вторым параметром не текущий элемент, а следующий

```js
var ptag = document.getElementById('idName');

var newhr = document.createElement('hr');
ptag.parentNode.insertBefore(newhr, ptag.nextElementSibling);
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p id="idName">Paragraph idName</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</article>
```

---

Для случая нескольких `p`

---

```js
for (var ptag of document.getElementsByTagName('p')) {
  var newhr = document.createElement('hr');
  ptag.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newhr);
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Grundy спасибо за помощь. Ваш код работает и помогло. Но тогда каждый раз приходиться обращаться на id. А у меня их очень много(там дизайнеры делает какой-то магия))

Comment: @СардарАтабеков, ничего не мешает получать элементы с помощью `getElementByTagName` и потом в цикле проходить по ним и вставлять что нужно.

Comment: @СардарАтабеков, Добавил пример. как можно заметить, сам код вставки не поменялся.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению нету ничего такого как insertAfter, поэтрому нужно комбинировать, и как один из вариантов:

```
var getChildIndex = function(child) {
  var parent = child.parentNode;

  for (var i = 0; i !== parent.children.length; i++) {
    if (parent.children[i] === child) {
      return i;
    }
  }
};

var insertAfter = function(el) {
  var ind = getChildIndex(el);
  var hr = document.createElement('hr');

  if (ind === el.parentNode.children.length - 1) {
    el.parentNode.appendChild(hr);
  } else {
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(hr, el.parentNode.children[ind + 1]);
  }
};

var artic = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
var ptag = artic[0].querySelectorAll('p');

for (var i = 0; i !== ptag.length; i++) {
  insertAfter(ptag[i]);
}
```